# Scala spark find median in a window partition

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, bigdata

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = 
--------------
|col1 | col2 |
--------------
| A   | 1    |
| A   | 5    |
| B   | 0    |
| A   | 2    |
| B   | 6    |
| B   | 8    |
--------------
```

I want to partition by col1, find the median of col2 in each partition, and append the result to form a new column. The result should look like this:

```
result = 
---------------------
|col1 | col2 | col3 |
---------------------
| A   | 1    | 2    |
| A   | 5    | 2    |
| B   | 0    | 6    |
| A   | 2    | 2    |
| B   | 6    | 6    |
| B   | 8    | 8    |
---------------------
```

For now, I'm using this code:

```
val df2 = df
.withColumn("tmp", percent_rank over Window.partition('col1).orderBy('col2))
.where("tmp <= 0.5")
.groupBy("col1").agg(max(col2) as "col3")

val result = df.join(df2, df("col1") === df2("col1")).drop(df2("col1"))
```

But this takes too much time and space resources to run when the dataframe is big. Please help me find a way to do the above more efficiently!
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data you have, you can do a Spark DataFrame `groupBy` statement with `percentile_approx` to perform the calculation.

```
// Creating the `df` dataset
val df = Seq(("A", 1), ("A", 5), ("B", 0), ("A", 2), ("B", 6), ("B", 8)).toDF("col1", "col2")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
```

Use `percentile_approx` with `groupBy` to perform median calculation:

```
val df2 = spark.sql("select col1, percentile_approx(col2, 0.5) as median from df group by col1 order by col1")
df2.show()
```

with the output of `df2` being:

```
+----+------+
|col1|median|
+----+------+
|   A|   2.0|
|   B|   6.0|
+----+------+
```

And now running the `join` to recreate the final result:

```
val result = df.join(df2, df("col1") === df2("col1"))
result.show()

//// output
+----+----+----+------+
|col1|col2|col1|median|
+----+----+----+------+
|   A|   1|   A|   2.0|
|   A|   5|   A|   2.0|
|   B|   0|   B|   6.0|
|   A|   2|   A|   2.0|
|   B|   6|   B|   6.0|
|   B|   8|   B|   6.0|
+----+----+----+------+
```